# How to implement Stripe Payments in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-web

I'm trying to implement Stripe Payments in my Web App ( Flutter ) and I couldn't find any packages in https://pub.dev/ to fulfil my wishes. For my iOS and Android apps I used https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment , but I saw a tutorial on some Stripe Checkout with JS in Flutter. My question is, besides how to implement Stripe Payments in Flutter web, isn't that Insecure? I mean I declare the keys in the HTML file, and if anyone Right Click -> Inspect, is able to see my key?

Can you suggest a good way to implement Stripe Payments in my Flutter Web App?

Comment: What are you questioning is insecure?

Comment: Stripe has a publishable (public) key and a secret (private) key. That package is using the publishable key, which is fine.

Comment: i got it, thank you

Comment: how did you solve the issue @CalinOnaca?

Comment: This might help you: 

link: https://fidev.io/stripe-checkout-in-flutter-web/

Comment: How can I capture payment Intent in Flutter Web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ceejayoz said in the comments - as long as you're using the Publishable Key in your app - and never your Secret Key - it's fine.